# Why the number of samples in a leaf doesn't match the number of values in parent node for DecisionTreeClassifier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a python script which creates a `DecisionTreeClassifier` for a dataset and then draws a graph of this tree. The issue is that the number of samples in a leaf is always different from the split in the parent node. For example for the root node the has value=[4267, 6669], but it's right side node has only 828 samples.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
# Create Decision Tree classifier object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=8, min_samples_split=0.03, min_samples_leaf=0.01)

# Train Decision Tree Classifier
clf = clf.fit(X_train_ohe, y_train)

# Predict the response for test dataset
X_test_ohe = ohe.transform(X_test)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_ohe)

print("Accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
plt.figure(figsize=(48, 24))
plot_tree(clf,
          feature_names=ohe_df.columns,
          class_names=np.unique(y).astype('str'),
          filled=True,
          fontsize=10)
```

Why is it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the number of samples (see `samples` in your graph), your root node with 10,936 samples is split into nodes with 10,108 and 828 samples, so it adds up (10,108 + 828 = 10,936).

And if you look at the `value` (which shows how many samples of each class you have in each node), you can see that:

- for the first class (`Bad`): 4,267 in the root node is the sum of 3,439 in the left child and 828 in the right child
- for the second class (`Good`): 6,669 is the sum of 6,669 (left) and 0 (right)